# When will MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() return false?

Tags: ios, sms, apple-developer

Does anyone know exactly when will iOS `MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()` return false? Based on Apple's documentation, it states that:

```
A device may be unable to send messages if it does not support messaging or if it is not currently configured to send messages.
```

When I test, it returns false on iPhone simulators (which made sense). But on physical device, it always return true although there's no sim card installed. It's kinda vague on what is considered `unable to send messages` @@

Update:
Based on [this book](https://books.google.com.my/books?id=BPJGDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA228#v=snippet&q=canSendText()&f=false), it states that:

`If you try to run the app in the simulator or on a phone without a SIM card the MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() will always returns false.`

which is not true from what I tested

Comment: Perhaps the statement about requiring a SIM card predates iMessage. IMessage can send a message to another iMessage recipient as long as there is internet connectivity.

Comment: I also h ave found the language in this area unclear... for physical devices, you should consider several scenarios. iPhone (w/ or w/o SIM, w/ or w/o iMessage logged in). iPad (w/ or w/o iMessage... even if the device has data, SMS/MMS is not part of that).